# Find $D_{A,B}$ satisfying $\int_{-A}^{B}\hat{f}(t)e^{2\pi itx} dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y) D_{A,B}(y) dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Find for $A,B > 0$ a function $D_{A,B}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ so that \begin{align}
\int_{-A}^{B}\hat{f}(t)e^{2\pi itx} dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y) D_{A,B}(y) dy
\end{align}

My attempt:
\begin{align}
\int_{-A}^{B}\hat{f}(t)e^{2\pi itx} dt&=\int_{-A}^{B}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) e^{-2\pi itx}e^{2\pi itx} dt\\
&=\int_{-A}^{B}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x) dxdt\\
\end{align}
because of Fubini
\begin{align}
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-A}^{B}f(x) dtdx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)(B+A)dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x-y)(-B-A)dy
\end{align}

My function $D_{A,B}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ would be $(-A-B)$. I think I did something wrong because my funtion is independent of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the Fourier transform of $f$ should not re-use the variable $x$, so the cancellation doesn't make sense. Instead, notice that if we let $\chi_{[-A,B]}$ denote the characteristic function on $[-A,B]$, then
$$\int\limits_{-A}^B\hat{f}(t)e^{2\pi itx}\, dt=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{[-A,B]}(t)\hat{f}(t)e^{2\pi itx}\, dt=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{[-A,B]}\mathcal{F} f)(x)=f*\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{[-A,B]})(x)$$ by the convolution theorem, and
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)D_{A,B}(y)\, dy= f*D_{A,B}(x).$$ So, $$D_{A,B}(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\chi_{[-A,B]})(x)=\int\limits_{-A}^B e^{2\pi i tx}\, dt=\frac{e^{2\pi i Bx}-e^{-2\pi i Ax}}{2\pi i x}$$